# AWS RDS Aurora PostgreSQL serverless: How to set public accessibility to Yes

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-aurora-serverless

we have a instance of AWS RDS Aurora PostgreSQL Serverless with a vpc security group associated allowing connections from any place and any port, but we are unable to connect. 
we always get the error "could not connect to server: Connection timed out "

We have found references to "public accessibility" parameter to solve the problem, but we are unable to find where to make the change.

Any help? 
THanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aurora Serverless does not support publicly accessible endpoints at this time. It must be accessed from inside the VPC. Make sure you are attempting to connect to Aurora from within the VPC, and that the security group assigned to the Aurora cluster has the appropriate rules to allow access.

Comment: Mark, Thank you for your quick and useful answer.